# Lenses for fast-paced environment

Tags: lens

What two lenses should you carry to be able to take a majority of shots in a fast paced environment?

Or more specifically: I just watched a documentary on PBS about Pete Souza, the current White House Photographer.  He's always running and having to take split-second photos of the president.  Does anyone know what he carries around?

Comment: I have Canon bodies.  One of the cameras that Pete Souza was shooting with inside didn't have a flash.  Would it have been something faster than a 2.8?

Comment: He uses the 5D2 and mostly primes, especially the 35 1.4. Check out the Whitehouse Flickr stream, http://www.flickr.com/photos/whitehouse/ All the Exif data is left intact. The 70-200 will popup a few times in there. I've seen a 50 1.2 before.

Comment: The very first photo that I clicked on at the whitehouse flickr stream was a Canon EF24-70mm f/2.8L II USM. He's upgraded to a 5D3

Answer (score 8):

Many event photographers carry two primary lenses which cover most focal lengths needed for typical walkaround photos:

- 24-70mm f/2.8
- 70-200mm f/2.8

Based on what you describe, those would be my two go-to lenses.

Comment: Erik did not say what system he is using. This would be the perfect full-frame Nikon combo. For a cropped-sensor, there is usually a 16-50 or 17-55 or 17-50 F/2.8 (different for each brand) that would replace the 24-70. I know some who even do with a middle-range gap by going with a 16-35mm F2.8 as their wide option. Of course you always carry 2 cameras as well to not have to change lenses. That would be a no-no in fast-paced environments.

Comment: These two lenses work fine for full-frame cameras. If there's not much light and you're allowed to use it, flash it also great for freezing action.

Comment: I really dislike the 70-200 when shooting weddings, at least the Nikon version.  It is super heavy and extremely painful to carry around for hours on end.  I go with the 85mm f/1.8 instead.  Much smaller, therefore I can aim it at the end of five hours of lifting it.

Answer (score 4):

If I were photographing a President, I would want something that is very fast, has a reasonable zoom, and definitely image stabilization. That'd be the 70-200mm 2.8L with IS. As for a second, well, probably the 24-105 f/4 L.

Note that I don't own either, but they'd be what I would choose, if I had to, so...

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the sort of distance you are at, but if you want to limit it to 2 lenses I would suggest zooms. For fast paced you would want fast lenses (small f number) so this would bring me to the 70-200f2.8 (available on both Canon & Nikon systems) and probably the 24-70f2.8 (also available on both systems). The only problem is that on a cropped sensor camera 24-70mm may not be wide enough.

However in this sort of situation I would use two bodies as wel as 2 lenses as you could easily miss the moment while you are changing lens.

Answer (score 0):

A zoom lens offers great versatility and with FF DSLRs nowadays, higher ISOs can really perform quite well. So I would think that the fastest f/2.8 or f/4 of the top-of-the-line general "walk around" zooms from Canon or Sigma or Tamron would be a good bet.

If I needed to get a second lens, I would actually go for a fast prime, like f/1.2 or f/1.4. But the length depends on how far you're usually working away from your subject. The dof and the way you shoot with a prime may lead to some different angles which will be more interesting than the usual 70-200 look in my personal opinion.